# Are you meant to recover from contract violations?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

With the guideline support library and utilities like [`gsl_Expects`](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite) C++ implements contracts for the time being (there are plans to bake this stuff into the language in the future).  Using this feature and depending on your project setup, contract violation will likely:

- throw an exception or
- call terminate

I was wondering what the recovery strategy should be. Obviously in the second case (where you set up contract violations to call terminate) there's none, but even in the first case it's hard to recover; since the exception is of some inner type (e.g. `fail_fast` which derives from `logic_error`) it's hard to structure a recovery strategy: what exception(s) should I catch, at which level, is there useful information that will help me recover (I think file+line is meant for a human reader to do a post mortem analysis).

So given all that, my question is: **Are you meant to recover from contract violations? If yes how?** Is there a source describing how to do it? If not, is it a good idea to separate my error checking+handling from contract checking and only think about contracts in terms of hard errors?

I guess the second choice is what I'm leaning towards but the annoying thing is that these violations will cause my whole program to crash instead of nulling out a single function.

I could structure contract bearing functions like this:

```
std::optional<return_t> my_function(Arg arg)
{
  std::optional<return_t> ret;

  try {
    gsl_Expects(...); // do contract checking 
    /* rest of function */
  } catch (fail_fast& e) {
    // report contract violation
  }

  return ret;  // Exceptions from contract violations are turned into empty optional
               // Other exceptions are handled like before (locally or from the caller)
}
```

but it feels like it beats the purpose of using contracts.

Comment: I think this depends on why you are using contracts in the first place.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Can you describe a use of contracts where recovery is achievable? Even treating them as exceptions makes rollback a nightmare. I'd love to see an example of such a strategy.

Comment: The article section [Bugs Aren’t Recoverable Errors!](http://joeduffyblog.com/2016/02/07/the-error-model/#bugs-arent-recoverable-errors) by Joe Duffy discusses this kind of situation.  And although the article is for a different programming language, it is generally applicable to all programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

You're not meant to recover from contract errors. A contract error is a logical error in your program, in other words your program is wrong. There's no plausible way to recover from that, the best you can do is to kill and restart the entire subsystem the failure occurred in and hope it's a rare failure.

Exceptional situations you can anticipate shouldn't be handled by contracts, that's what the exception mechanism is for.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer. I'm leaning towards the same opinion. The problem is in the practicality of this. Take for example a square root function. Of course a contract check would be that the number is positive (I think that the example given in the guidelines) but why should failure in `square root` cause my program to crash?

Comment: Because the alternative would be to continue running the program in an unknown invalid state, which is worse. I can't think of a situation where that would be acceptable but a crash wouldn't be.

Comment: or report an error and discard that computation

Comment: That can only work if you know _why_ the error occurred. Of course you'll know for situations you can think of, but situations you can think of you should handle with explicit error checking anyway. Contracts are for catching errors you didn't think of, which could theoretically be caused by any part of your program misbehaving. That's what I'm alluding to in my second paragraph, if you want to handle a subsystem of your program being wrong you need to isolate, let it crash and restart it when it does.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some strategy.

Assume a program shows some UI, user opens some file, and as that file is corrupted, loading the data violates some contracts.

Exception handling wouldn't do some "recovery" in terms of restoring consistent state of file structure, instead it would just destroy file-associated structures, and reports an error.

This is still not "hard" error. UI-associated structures are intact, and program may continue.

Sure this may be considered not very good practice. Ideally, all external data is validated, and so there's no contract violations on bad data, so contract violations are fatal. Not sure if you are writing ideal programs. I don't.